# How to add element to vector and return reference to that element?

Tags: rust, ownership

I am trying my hand at a simple XML writer in Rust by first building a tree of tags in memory.

In the function `add_child` below, I want to add the newly created child element to the current element's list of children, then return that child so that the caller can in turn add other children to that child. But I can't, because the child is then owned by the vector.

What is the "idiomatic" way to do this sort of thing in Rust?

I suppose I could let the consumer of my `tag.rs` library manipulate the list of children in the struct themselves, but then the implementation details are not neatly contained in a function.

Is there another/better way to do this?

```
// tag.rs
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct Tag<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    attributes: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>,
    children: Vec<Tag<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Tag<'a> {
    pub fn new(name: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self {
            name,
            attributes: HashMap::new(),
            children: vec![],
        }
    }

    pub fn add_child(&mut self, name: &'a str) -> Self {
        let mut child = Self::new(name);
        self.children.push(child); // `child` moved here
        child // <-- Error: use of moved value: `child`        
    }

    pub fn add_attribute(&mut self, key: &'a str, value: &'a str) {
        self.attributes.insert(key, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a mutable reference to the last element:

```rust
pub fn add_child(&mut self, name: &'a str) -> &mut Self {
    let mut child = Self::new(name);
    self.children.push(child); // `child` moved here
    self.children.last_mut().unwrap()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! But how does the compiler allow that without breaking the ownership contract? I thought that, because the vector now owns the reference, you cannot give a mutable reference of it to another function?

Comment: @mydoghasworms you have a mutable reference to the child, which means you can do most things except drop it. It also means you cannot interact with the parent until you stop using the mutable reference.

Comment: @mydoghasworms you can't keep a reference to the original, but *after moving it* you can get a reference *through its owner* (the vec), that's the point of having first class references. However it limits what you can do with the parent (vec) since you already have a borrow on it to get at the child.